# File Level Restore - Confused over access to Data Recovery appliance

Tags: vmware-vdr

I must be confused. I have VMWare Data Recovery woking somewhat reliably. I decided to check out the FLR capability. I installed the FLR client on a Windows box, but when I configure it to point to my Data Recovery appliance, I've got a problem. My Data Recovery appliance is over in the vmware "management" network where the VMWare service consoles are located. (Isn't this typical?)

Since my guest operating systems are not in the same network as the service consoles, how are you supposed to get the FLR client to talk to the VMWare Data Recovery applicance? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FLR client needs to talk to the DR VM - there's nothing wrong with having the DR VM in your management network so long as your FLR VM can route to it - just make it so!